# ¿De que manera el elemento raíz genera un contexto de formato de bloque?

Tags: css

¿Porque se dice que el elemento raíz o algo que lo contiene genera un contexto de formato de bloque? ¿De que manera lo hace?

Empece a estudiar este concepto con un articulo de MDN que dice lo siguiente:

> Un contexto de formato de bloque es creado por uno de los siguientes
>   casos:
>
> - El elemento raiz o algo que lo contiene flotantes (elementos donde    float es diferente de none)
> - elementos con posición absoluta    (elementos donde position es    absolute o fixed)
> - bloques en línea    (elementos con display: inline-block)
> - Celdas de tabla (elementos con    display: table-cell, que es la    propiedad por defecto de las celdas de    una tabla HTML)
> - subtítulos de tabla (elementos con display:    table-caption, que es    la propiedad por defecto de los subtítulos de    tablas HTML)
> - elementos donde overflow tiene un valor distinto a
> - visible cajas flexibles (elementos con display: flex or inline-flex)

Comprendí fácilmente el porque flexbox genera un contexto, por lo que en la caja en donde se aplica, los hijos se colocan en el padre en base a un eje formado en las dimensiones del padre pero no entiendo el porque en casos como el elemento raíz se forma un contexto ni tampoco la manera en que `position: absolute` o `fixed` crean un contexto.

Tampoco entendí el porque los elementos flotantes generan un contexto de formato de bloque, ¿Esto ultimo tiene que ver con overflow? es decir ¿`float` y `overflow` trabajando juntos generan un contexto en el que el contenedor al tener `overflow: auto` permite envolver elementos flotantes como si estuvieran en el flujo? ¿no se ven por separados si no que estos dos generan un contexto juntos?

Comment: Podrías leer este articulo (en ingles) [Understanding CSS Layout And The Block Formatting Context](https://www.smashingmagazine.com//2017/12/understanding-css-layout-block-formatting-context/) y este otro [Everything You Need To Know About CSS Margins](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/margins-in-css/#parent-first-last-child-element) para entender **que es** un contexto de formato de bloque, pero no **porque lo es**.  Lo es porque fue creado que lo sea